# simple search in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code for search in mysql but it doesent run and i dont know why.

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>search Employees</legend> 
     <form name="search" method="post" action= <?=$PHP_SELF?>>
     Αναζήτηση για: <input type="text" name="find" /> στο
     <Select NAME="field">
     <Option VALUE="fname">First Name</option>
     <Option VALUE="lname">Surname</option>
     <Option VALUE="phone">Phone</option>
     <Option VALUE="address">Address</option>
     </Select>
     <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
     <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
     </form>
     </fieldset>
    <? 
     //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
     if ($searching =="yes") 
     { 
     echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 

     //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
     if ($find == "") 
     { 
     echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
     exit; 
     } 

     // Otherwise we connect to our Database 
     mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123") or die(mysql_error()); 
     mysql_select_db("ergasia2") or die(mysql_error()); 

     // We preform a bit of filtering 
     $find = strtoupper($find); 
     $find = strip_tags($find); 
     $find = trim ($find); 

     //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
     $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'"); 

     //And we display the results 
     while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
     { 
     echo $result['fname']; 
     echo " "; 
     echo $result['lname']; 
     echo "<br>"; 
     echo $result['info']; 
     echo "<br>"; 
     echo "<br>"; 
     } 

     //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
     $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
     if ($anymatches == 0) 
     { 
     echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
     } 

     //And we remind them what they searched for 
     echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
     } 

 ?>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You should be getting some errors. What does `mysql_error()` return? Any other errors? Also, if $find is outside data, you *need* to do `mysql_real_escape_string()` on it

Comment: $field should be $_POST['field'], same with $find

Comment: and $searching too: $searching = $_POST['searching']. If $searching is not equal to "yes", than all the code isn't executed at all

Answer (score 2):

Your code assumes that [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is turned on (new installs of php this is defaulted to off) this should be **off** as it is a security risk. I would suggest reading a tutorial for creating a SQL Search which shows security etc.

Instead of going into what is wrong, I wrote this tutorial up, perhaps it will help you out: [Simple SQL Search](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/simple-sql-search)

Comment: This won't fix OP's problem, but +1 anyway for mentioning about **not using** *register_globals*.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because your query is wrong. You cannot use `UPPER` on column names like this. Also, not sure if your field name is like `FIELD` (full uppercase) or like `Field` (capitalize first letter only). And don't forget to escape your input!

Try this:

```
$escaped_field = mysql_real_escape_string($field);
$field_name = strtoupper($escaped_field); // if you want FIELD
$field_name = ucfirst($escaped_field);    // if you want Field
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE `$field_name` LIKE '%$find%'");
```

I might add, if your table names/column names really are full uppercase (e.g.: `FIELD`), you might want to change this. Uppercase keywords are generally reserved keywords, so it can be confusing.

Comment: I never heard that about uppercase. I do not think it matters one way or the other. Your preference is to keep keywords upper case, but keywords and column names can be in whatever case you want them to be.

Comment: @Brad: I know they can be whatever case you want them to be, but still, when I look at this, I still think it can be confusing. Just a suggestion you know.

Comment: Not a problem, you just presented it like fact. :) Just clearing up the air a bit. (That is my preference as well)